# Recovering lost local files from .git

Tags: git, bitbucket

So yesterday I made a push of my code to a Bitbucket repo. After realizing this was the incorrect repo to push to, I did a `git reset --hard` to remove the commit. However, after doing that, I noticed that my local files were deleted. Sadly, I did not create a backup of those recent files. Yes, I do have a much older copy of those files.

I've explored the `.git` folder and see that the commit prior to my `git reset --hard` is there. However, I am not sure how to get to the files within that commit. The `.git` folder has all of the appropriate folders: hooks, info, logs, objects, refs, as well as the main directory files (ie. HEAD, description, etc).

If I do a `git fsck --full`, I get a few errors:

```
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry a5564cddeffd7673cf418955f01bec5d4003f630
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry a5564cddeffd7673cf418955f01bec5d4003f630
error: refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry a5564cddeffd7673cf418955f01bec5d4    003f630
error: refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry a5564cddeffd7673cf418955f01bec5d4    003f630
dangling commit 141d684c3fd2d0da2d6df9844bfeea9e976c9b32
```

I looked in `.git/logs/refs/heads/master` to identify the commit I need.

The line with the one I want is this one:

```
452f1923ac02bfb1c0930ecfb39d7234db9b6f0f a5564cddeffd7673cf418955f01bec5d4003f630 [username] <email> 1594581184 -0500   commit: Initial commit
```

Is it even possible to get my files back? And if so, how can I do that? Thank you for any guidance you can provide! I normally back up my files, so this is uncharted territory for me.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR version of the linked answer :

```
git reflog
# copy the sha1 of the commit you want to return to
git reset --hard <sha1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps..

1. To list all commits in the order you last referenced them (i.e. history of where your HEAD pointer travelled) you do `git reflog`
2. Grab the hash of the commit just before the reset
3. Go to that commit by `git checkout <hash>`
4. Create a backup branch and switch to that branch `git switch -c backup`
5. Go back to the old branch `git checkout <branch_where_you_performed_reset>`
6. Merge the backup branch `git merge backup`
7. Delete the backup branch